# Почему не работает javascript(на сайте только текст)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
    <form action="test.js">
        <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="u_name" size="35">
        <p><b>Каким браузером вы пользуетесь?</b><br>
            <input type="radio" name="t" value="moz">mozilla<br>
            <input type="radio" name="t" value="chr">chrome<br>
            <input type="submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Это сама форма.

```
if(t==chr){
    alert(u_name + ", you're using chome")
}
else{
    alert(u_name + ", you're using mozilla")
}
```

Это файл `test.js`.
Почему на сайте после отправки формы у меня вылезает страница с кодом и никаких действий не происходит?

Comment: А почему должно происходить что-то другое?

Comment: А как сделать чтобы код выполнялся?

Comment: Поместите его в html-тег `<script>`, очевидно. Но даже после этого ничего не заработает, потому что у вас не существуют переменные `t` и`chr`. Читайте учебники по javascript

Comment: да и   <header>  тега с метатегами  похоже нету